# How to config testcafe basic configuration on ES modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, config, testcafe

[TypeScript and CoffeeScript](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402824/guides/intermediate-guides/typescript-and-coffeescript)

The testcafe documentation says that no additional settings are needed to use ES modules when writing tests, however, it's not clear how to configure the testcafe configuration if the project uses ES modules, for example to write global hooks. Because it looks line you have only 2 options to config testcafe globaly: .json and CommomJS

I need authorization before each test in the project, and I have this function for that:

```
import { Role, Selector, t } from 'testcafe';

export const user = Role('http://localhost:3000/login', async t => {
    await t
        .typeText(Selector('#loginInput'), 'Login')
        .typeText(Selector('#passwordInput'), 'Password')
        .click(Selector('button').withAttribute('data-testid', 'submitButton'));        
});
```

And I have tried this in .testcafers.js file

```
import { user } from './src/testing/utilities/loginUser';

export default {
  hooks: {
    testRun: {
      before: async () => {
        await t.useRole(user)
      }
    },
  }
};
```

To summarize, how can I write a global hook for testcafe, if my project is using ES modules

Answer (score 0):

There is an exception for the config file. You should use CommonJS syntax as described in [the documentation](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402638/reference/configuration-file#javascript).

```js
const { user } = require('./src/testing/utilities/loginUser');

module.exports = {
  hooks: {
    testRun: {
      before: async () => {
        await t.useRole(user)
      }
    },
  }
};
```